# JS - Child element to not listen to delegated event

Tags: javascript, html, css

In the following snippet you will see a delegated event attached to `document`.

The key thing to note is:

```
if (e.target.parentNode.id === 'put-stuff-here') {
  e.target.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

```js
function loadItems(target) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="new"><span>Click me!</span>Or click me!</div>');
    }, (i * 250));
  }
}

document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  loadItems(document.getElementById('put-stuff-here'));
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.parentNode.id === 'put-stuff-here') {
    e.target.classList.toggle('active');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'arial';
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
body > * {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
#put-stuff-here:before {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  content: 'Target Location:';
  background-color: PapayaWhip;
}
#put-stuff-here {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.new {
  background-color: SteelBlue;
  padding: 8px;
}
.new span {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  margin: 8px;
}
.active {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<button>Press Me!</button>
<div id="put-stuff-here">

</div>
```

As you can see, if you click on the "red-bordered span" it will not work, but if you click on the div it works. I know the reason for this and the "solution" is:

```
if (e.target.parentNode.id === 'put-stuff-here' || e.target.parentNode.parentNode.id === 'put-stuff-here') {
  e.target.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

This; however, does not fully work, and causes this (click on both the span and then the div):

```js
function loadItems(target) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="new"><span>New!</span></div>');
    }, (i * 250));
  }
}

document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  loadItems(document.getElementById('put-stuff-here'));
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.parentNode.id === 'put-stuff-here' || e.target.parentNode.parentNode.id === 'put-stuff-here') {
    e.target.classList.toggle('active');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'arial';
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
body > * {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
#put-stuff-here:before {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  content: 'Target Location:';
  background-color: PapayaWhip;
}
#put-stuff-here {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.new {
  background-color: SteelBlue;
  padding: 8px;
}
.new span {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  margin: 8px;
}
.active {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<button>Press Me!</button>
<div id="put-stuff-here">

</div>
```

There are various other methods I have tested, including:

```
if (e.target.parentNode.id === 'put-stuff-here' || e.target.parentNode.parentNode.id === 'put-stuff-here') {
  e.target.classList.toggle('active') || e.target.parentNode.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

But they all do not do what I want, which is: **when you click *anywhere* in the `div`, it will toggle the `active` class**

> I think the solution lies somewhere event bubbling, but I have not been able to find a way to utilize this. Is there a way for child events to "ignore" event handlers on (non-)delegated events?

A jsfiddle for this can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/wu7257em/1/).

*P.S. I know another way to do this is:*

```
if (e.target.classList.contains('new') || e.target.parentNode.classList.contains('new')) {
  e.target.classList.toggle('active');
}
```

*and all the other variations, etc. but that runs into the same problem that I list above.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pointer-events`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events):

> The CSS property `pointer-events` allows authors to control under what
>   circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the
>   target of mouse events.

```css
.new > * {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```js
function loadItems(target) {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      target.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="new"><span>Click me!</span>Or click me!</div>');
    }, (i * 250));
  }
}

document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  loadItems(document.getElementById('put-stuff-here'));
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.parentNode.id === 'put-stuff-here') {
    e.target.classList.toggle('active');
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'arial';
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
body > * {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}
#put-stuff-here:before {
  display: block;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: center;
  content: 'Target Location:';
  background-color: PapayaWhip;
}
#put-stuff-here {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.new {
  background-color: SteelBlue;
  padding: 8px;
}
.new > span {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  margin: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
.active {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<button>Press Me!</button>
<div id="put-stuff-here">

</div>
```

Comment: wow, who would have known the solution would have been in CSS! This works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

> I think the solution lies somewhere event bubbling, but I have not been able to find a way to utilize this. Is there a way for child events to "ignore" event handlers on (non-)delegated events?

Yes event bubbling is part of the solution, and utilizing the properties of `event.target` and `event.currentTarget` will help you isolate a specific element along the event chain.

#### SNIPPET

```js
// Reference the parent element
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');

// add an eventListener to the parent element
parent.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

  /*
  | While in bubbling phase, we only want event.target
  | (i.e. the element that was clicked on) and not
  | all of the other elements that happen to be on the
  | event chain (i.e. event.currentTarget)
  */

  if (event.target !== event.currentTarget) {

    // Store the event.target in a var
    var tgt = event.target;

    // Do whatever you want to event.target
    tgt.classList.toggle('active');
  }
  /*
  | Stop any further bubbling so that event.target is
  | the only element on the event chain that reacts to
  | the click event.
  */
  event.stopPropagation();
}, false);
```

```css
#parent {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  border: 3px dashed red;
  padding: 10px;
}
.child {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .75);
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 5px;
  height: 15px;
}
.active {
  background: red;
  outline: 2px dotted orange;
}
```

```html
<main id='parent'>
  <section class='child'></section>
  <section class='child'></section>
  <section class='child'></section>
  <section class='child'></section>
  <section class='child'></section>
  <section class='child'></section>
  <section class='child'></section>
  <section class='child'></section>
  <section class='child'></section>
  <section class='child'></section>
</main>
```

Comment: tku, makes sense. I attempted it in my code but am still running into the same problem as above. You can see my attempt in [this updated jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wu7257em/2/). Maybe I duplicated something incorrectly?

Comment: Did you want to toggle the "NEW" blue and white? I commented out the `e.stopPropagation();` in order to allow bubbling since each child is within it's own parent. If you wrapped your generated divs in a container that all of the children have in common as their parent, then you'd have a stable and simple way of using one event handler and listener for an unlimited amount of siblings. https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/3r594m84/1/

Comment: tku. No, I wanted the entire div to become `active` when you click on anywhere in the div (i.e. no matter where you click, the entire field will become active). I thought I made that clear in the OP that I wanted that, but in re-reading it see that it could have been misinterpreted.

Comment: Ok, you actually want to capture each hit on the event chain. So if an element that's 3 levels down is clicked, you'd like to capture all 3 elements along the way down or on the way back?